# Get position of first and last char in substring

Tags: string, substring, ocaml

I would like to make a function in OCaml that return the position of the first and last char in a substring. For example `my_sub "tar" "ar"` will return `(1,2)` but if I have `my_sub "tabr" "ar"` it will be `Nil`, it must be consecutive. How can I do that ?

**Edit**

I tried to make the code but I have a problem

```
let rec pos_sub l t n =
  let rec aux l1 l2 x =
    match l1, l2 with
    | [], _ | _, [] | [], [] -> -1
    | h1::q1, h2 | h1, h2 -> if h1 = h2 then x else -1
    | h1::q1, h2::q2 -> if h1 = h2 then aux q1 q2 x+1 else -1
  in
  match l, t with
  | [], _ -> (-1,-1)
  | h1::q1, h2::q2 -> if h1 = h2 then (n, (aux q1 q2 n+1)) else pos_sub q1 t n+1
```

it says :

> The variable h1 on the left-hand side of this or-pattern has type 'a
>          but on the right-hand side it has type 'a list
>          The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list

in the second match in `aux`

Comment: This really isn't a code-writing service. What are your own thoughts on how to solve it and the challenges involved? Have you considered using [Str](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html)?

Comment: I know that I have to find the first occurence of "a" on "tar" and then check if the next one is "r" in java or c I would that easily but in ocaml it's really hard...

Comment: Why is it hard? You can write code very similar to Java and C in OCaml.

Comment: And why does the function you posted operate on a list, when you say you want a function that operates on a string?

Comment: Well actually I find easier to make it a string list

Comment: You just said OCaml was really hard, which I assume refers to the string list approach, and that it would be easy in Java and C. So have you tried doing it like Java and C?

Comment: What should `my_sub "tar$tar$tar" "tar"` return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in the code is, that in this match:

```
| h1::q1, h2 | h1, h2 -> if h1 = h2 then x else -1
```

you try to compare a single character `h1` with `h2` which is of type `string`. This is what the error message tries to tell you. I think you intended match the case, where `h2` is the last character of your search string, therefore:

```
| h1::q1, h2:[] | h1:[], h2:[] -> if h1 = h2 then x else -1
```

and because `q1` is unused, this can then be simplified to:

```
| h1::_, h2:[] -> if h1 = h2 then x else -1
```

A sidenode: it is bad style to use `-1` or similar as special values to signal error cases. Rather use optional types in such situations.